# SAML 2.0 invalid request SSOCIRCLE

Tags: saml-2.0

I am trying to send a SAML request to the public IDP SSOCircle. I imported its metadata and try to authenticate against this URL:

```
https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/idpssoinit?metaAlias=%2Fpublicidp&spEntityID=sp.bogdan.test
```

But when I send this request from my app, the following error is displayed:

> Error occurred Reason: The SAML Request is invalid.

this my request:
[a link](https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/SSOPOST/metaAlias/publicidp?SAMLRequest=PHNhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdCBJRD0iXzNiN2Y5MzdiLTA3M2QtNDI4OS1iMmQxLTM1ZTc4NmViYjUyNCIgVmVyc2lvbj0iMi4wIiBJc3N1ZUluc3RhbnQ9IjIwMTctMDQtMDNUMTI6NDI6MDZaIiBQcm90b2NvbEJpbmRpbmc9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpiaW5kaW5nczpIVFRQLVBPU1QiIEFzc2VydGlvbkNvbnN1bWVyU2VydmljZVVSTD0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo2MTM0NC9BY2NvdW50L0Fzc2VydGlvbkNvbnN1bWVyU2VydmljZSIgeG1sbnM6c2FtbHA9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpwcm90b2NvbCI%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%3d)

and this is the SAML message in the request that I wrote:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="_3b7f937b-073d-4289-b2d1-35e786ebb524" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-04-03T12:42:06Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:61344/Account/AssertionConsumerService">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" AllowCreate="true"/>
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
            urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
        </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are sending *https://idp.ssocircle.com* as the Issuer of the AuthnRequest. The Issuer of the request is not the **IDP** but the **SP**. In your case it should be *sp.bogdan.test*

Answer (score 1):

It may be as simple as not having registered the right Assertion Consumer URL (`http://localhost:61344/Account/AssertionConsumerService`) with SSOCircle. But you should really look in to the SSOCircle debug logs to find out more.